# Using Rules Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rules, rule-engine

I have the following situation -

I have `Company` and I have `Incident`.

A `Company` offers many services (`Service`) and hence - `has_and_belongs_to_many :services`.

An `Incident` needs some services (`Service`) and hence - `has_and_belongs_to_many :services`

Now for a given incident I need to find all the companies that offer the services I need. I am looking to use a rules engine to do this because I have a lot more complex conditions to apply to pick the right set of companies.

I looked into this gem called - `Wongi-engine` (github.com/ulfurinn/wongi-engine), but its too hard to wrap my head around it and write rules.

Can you provide any pointers for me? Thanks!

I can come up with following `facts`:

```
engine << [ "CompanyA", "offers", "serviceA" ]
engine << [ "CompanyB", "offers", "serviceB" ]
engine << [ "CompanyA", "offers", "serviceB" ]
engine << [ "CompanyB", "offers", "serviceC" ]
engine << [ "IncidentA", "requires", "serviceC" ]
engine << [ "IncidentA", "requires", "serviceA" ]
```

EDIT:
Also once I write these rules, how do I use Rails models in place of these strings? And are there any best practices for loading the facts into the engine in the context of a Ruby on Rails application?

My usecase is, user selects an incident and asks for companies that can service the incident. And I need to ask the Rules engine for a list of companies that can do the trick :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with nested iterations to the engine.

```
engine.each "IncidentA", "requires" :_  do |requires|
  engine.each :_, "offers", requires.object do |offers|
    puts "IncidentA can get #{requires.object} from #{offers.subject}"
  end
end
```

To do it as a rule...

```
suppliers = engine.rule "service suppliers" do
    forall {
        has :Company, "offers", :Service
        has :Incident, "requires", :Service
    }
end
```

Then using the rule, select for the type of incident and iterate for the information.

```
suppliers.tokens.select{|s| s[:Incident] == "IncidentA" }.each do |s|
  puts "#{s[:Incident} can get #{s[:Service]} from #{s[:Company]}"
end
```

To do it as a query...

```
q = engine.query "companies" do
  search_on :Incident
  forall {
      has :Company, "offers", :Service
      has :Incident, "requires", :Service
  }
end

engine.execute "companies", { Incident: "IncidentA" }
q.tokens.each do |s|
  puts "#{s[:Incident} can get #{s[:Service]} from #{s[:Company]}"
end
```

EDIT adding notes for your question about populating `facts`...

Assuming you have `Company` with an attribute `name` and `Incident` with an attribute `name` and `Service` with an attribute `name`

```
Company.joins(:services).select("companies.*, services.name as service_name").each do |company|
  engine << [company.name, "offers", company.service_name]
end

Incident.joins(:services).select("incidents.*, services.name as service_name").each do |incident|
  engine << [incident.name, "requires", incident.service_name]
end
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for this. All this makes soooo much more sense now. I'll try to incorporate this in my app.

Comment: Just one more thing, how do I integrate this with my rails app where I'll have service, incident & company models? And are there any good practices for loading facts into the engine? Thanks!! Edited question with this part :)

Comment: ok, I've modified the question to show how you could populate facts using some ActiveModel inner joins.

Comment: Thanks! :) Steve, just one more thing. Is it a good practice to keep these facts in the database or load them when we need to query or keep them cached in Redis or something? What are your suggestions?

Accepted your answer btw.